# Можно ли убрать последнюю итерацию в цикле?

Tags: java

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Loader {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Locale.setDefault(new Locale("eng"));
        Calendar nowCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        Calendar birthdayCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        birthdayCalendar.set(1998, Calendar.AUGUST, 25);

        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy" + " - E" );

        String formatted1 = format.format(birthdayCalendar.getTime());

        System.out.println("0 - " + formatted1);

        int i;

        for(i = 0; !birthdayCalendar.after(nowCalendar); i++) {
            birthdayCalendar.add(Calendar.YEAR, 1);
            String formatted2 = format.format(birthdayCalendar.getTime());
            System.out.println((i + 1) + " - " + formatted2);
        }

        String formatted3 = format.format(nowCalendar.getTime());
        System.out.println((i - 1) + " - " + formatted3);
    }
}
```

Нужно убрать последнюю итерацию в цикле, чтобы в консоль выводился последний прошедший день рождения, а затем возраст и время на данный момент.

Comment: Проверить сейчас не могу, но попробуйте перенести строчку ``birthdayCalendar.add(Calendar.YEAR, 1);`` в конец цикла.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    i = 1;
    while(true) {
        birthdayCalendar.add(Calendar.YEAR, 1);
        if (birthdayCalendar.after(nowCalendar))
            break;
        String formatted2 = format.format(birthdayCalendar.getTime());
        System.out.println(i++ + " - " + formatted2);
    }
```